# Slow Video Processing

Tags: raspbian-stretch, opencv, python-2.x

I installed OpenCV libraries in raspberry pi for my project "Air Hockey Robot" and I'm using python for video processing. I am using PS3 eye camera for video capture at 60 fps. But it seems that video processing is too much slow. Should I use multi-threading or that's the general problem with Raspberry Pi 3?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't think 60 fps is achievable, even on a Pi 3. While the Pi 3 is fast *for a Raspberry Pi*, the processor is still only 1.2 GHz. That said, you could do a few things to help and see if it is achievable with some optimisation; OpenCV itself is in C++ which won't experience such large performance problems as Python does.

You can check to see what the cause of your largest delays are using a profiler like [`cProfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html) for Python; this would help you to determine which of your functions are taking the longest, and which you should focus on optimising.

You could consider using a lower frame rate instead which could increase your processing time per frame, or experiment to see if multithreading helps. Python is often a little bit problematic to thread due to the [general interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) which prevents two threads of the interpreter from running simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for getting higher frame rate like you said you could do threading. Other options which might be better only run video capture on it no other code, ncstick, or use the pi cam.  Most likely the cam you are using is for more robust systems hence why you are having lower frame rates.